# validating a belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I'm trying to validate a model Student like this;

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
end
```

I want to ensure that Room is a valid model, and with that I can only save a student only if the room is valid.

I tried to change the association to:

```
belongs_to :room, :validate => true
```

But it didnt change the behaviour..
API says:

```
:validate
  If false, don’t validate the associated objects when saving the parent object. false by default.
```

So I changed the validation to room:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students, :validate => true
end
```

but neither options solve for me

any ideas???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
  validates_associated :room
end
```

I'm looking at this portion of the API docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated

Also, be careful not to use that validation on *both* sides of the association!

Comment: NOTE: `validates_associated` will ensure the associated `room` record is `valid`, not that it is present. If it's `nil`, this validation will _not_ return with an error.